# How do I use an enum type as a map key in Hive

Tags: hive, thrift, hiveql

In Hive, we store complex data types using [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) [serdes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe) (serializer/deserializers).

As an example:

```
> describe foo.a_map;
a_map   map<AnEnumType,string>  from deserializer
```

We can access these things using [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/), but I'd like to use Hive.

If I try using an integer (which the enum type maps to), Hive barks.

```
select foo.a_map[0] from foo limit 10;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10032]: Line 2:7 MAP key type does not match index expression type '0'
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up exploding the map, lateral view, then casting to a string and matching the string.  Something like

```
select key1, value1
from foo
lateral view explode(a_map) foo_table as key1, value1
where cast(key1 as string) = '0'
```